# yq (GO/Mike Farah) sort all arrays recursively?

Tags: arrays, sorting, yaml, yq

**This is probably related to another question I posted:** [yq (GO/Mike Farah) uniquify all arrays recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746733/yq-go-mike-farah-uniquify-all-arrays-recursively)

Mike Farah's `yq` provides documentation for [sorting arrays](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/sort) but I'm having trouble figuring how to apply that to a list that is nested deeper

### Input

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - height
      - weight
      - age
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - model
      - manufacturer
      - color
      - year
```

### Desired output

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - age
      - height
      - weight
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - color
      - manufacturer
      - model
      - year
```

Naively trying to sort globally

```bash
cat to_sort.yaml | yq 'sort'
```

> Error: node at path [] is not an array (it's a !!map)

And if it takes arguments, I don't know what to provide. I don't want to just sort one explicit path, but I did try this:

```bash
cat to_sort.yaml | yq 'sort(classes.driver.fields)'
```

> Error: 1:6: invalid input text "classes.driver.f..."

I have seen some `yq` examples where one has to do a select operation first, but I don't know what to try in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yq e '(... | select(type == "!!seq")) |= sort' input
```

Will recursively loop over all the values, and [`select()`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select) those with `type` `!!seq` and update (`|=`) those with `sort`.

Applying OP's input to that filter gives:

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - age
      - height
      - weight
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - color
      - manufacturer
      - model
      - year
```

---

- `...`: [Recursive Descent](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob#match-values-and-map-keys-form-...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to first traverse there, then update the array (here, using the update `|=` operator).

Either one after another:

```bash
yq '
  .classes.driver.fields |= sort
  | .classes.vehicle.fields |= sort
' to_sort.yaml
```

Or both at once:

```bash
yq '
  (.classes.driver.fields, .classes.vehicle.fields) |= sort
' to_sort.yaml
```

Both output

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - age
      - height
      - weight
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - color
      - manufacturer
      - model
      - year
```