# yq (GO/Mike Farah) uniquify all arrays recursively

Tags: arrays, yaml, unique, yq

This is probably related to another question I posted: [yq (GO/Mike Farah) sort all arrays recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746627/yq-go-mike-farah-sort-all-arrays-recursively)

Mike Farah's `yq` provides documentation for [making arrays unique](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/unique) but I'm having trouble figuring how to apply that to lists that are nested deeper

### Input

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - height
      - age
      - age
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - model
      - model
      - color
      - year
```

### Desired output

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - age
      - height
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - color
      - model
      - year
```

Naively trying to globally uniqify

```bash
cat to_sort.yaml | yq 'unique'
```

> Error: Only arrays are supported for unique

And if it takes arguments, I don't know what to provide. I don't want to just sort one explicit path, but I did try this:

```bash
 cat to_sort.yaml | yq 'unique(.classes.driver.fields)'
```

> Error: Bad expression, please check expression syntax

I have seen some `yq` examples where one has to do a select operation first, but I don't know what to try in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 yq e '(... | select(type == "!!seq")) |= unique' input
```

Will recursively loop over all the items, and [`select()`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select) those of `type` `!!seq`

Then update (`|=`) those with `unique`:

Result from provided input:

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - height
      - age
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - model
      - color
      - year
```

---

- `...`: [Recursive Descent](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob#match-values-and-map-keys-form-...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to first traverse there, then update the array (here, using the update `|=` operator).

Either one after another:

```bash
yq '
  .classes.driver.fields |= unique
  | .classes.vehicle.fields |= unique
' to_sort.yaml
```

Or both at once:

```bash
yq '
  (.classes.driver.fields, .classes.vehicle.fields) |= unique
' to_sort.yaml
```

Both output

```yaml
classes:
  driver:
    fields:
      - height
      - age
  vehicle:
    fields:
      - model
      - color
      - year
```

Comment: Thats not really 'recursively', rather just defining the path yourself..

Comment: Oh, I missed that (as it was only in the title, not in the description). Updating...

Comment: Ok, I'm learning already. Apologies for misusing "recursively". Maybe what I meant to say is that I want to be able to apply this action to any arrays in the document.

Comment: Please consider 0stone0's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73747461/2158479) as it is exactly what I was about to turn this into.